# How to vectorize this function in py3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I seem to be unable to find out how to vectorize this py3 loop

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([-72, -10, -70, 37, 68, 9, 1, -3, 2, 3, -6, -4, ], np.int16)
result = np.array([-72, -10, -111, -23, 1, -2, 1, -3, 1, 2, -5, -5, ], np.int16)

b = np.copy(a)
for i in range(2, len(b)):
    b[i] += int( (b[i-1] + b[i-2]) / 2)

assert (b == result).all()
```

I tried playing with `np.convolve` and `pandas.rolling_apply` but couldn't get it working. Maybe this is the time to learn about c-extensions?

---

It would be great to get the time for this down to something like 50..100ms for input arrays of ~500k elements.

---

@hpaulj asked in his answer for a closed expression of `b[k]` in terms of `a[:k]`. I didn't think it existed, but I worked a bit on it and indeed found that the closed form contains a bunch of Jacobsthal numbers as @Divakar pointed out.

Here is one closed form:

[image: closed form using Jn]

`J_n` here is the [Jacobsthal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_number), when expanding it like this:

```
J_n = (2^n - (-1)^n) / 3
```

one ends up with an expression which I can imagine to use a vectorized implementation ...

[image: closed expression for b_k]

Comment: But `b` and `result` are different, right? Which is the correct expected output?

Comment: @Divakar integer division issue maybe? They are the same in Python 3.5.

Comment: @ayhan Exactly, this is supposed to run on py3.5. @Divakar the correct expected output is `result`

Comment: @ayhan Yeah seems so, as it works when we use `2.0` for division.

Comment: Well it seems the closed form would follow Jacobsthal Number. So, maybe look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Most `numpy` code operates on the whole array at once.  Ok it iterates in C code but buffered in a way that it doesn't matter which element is used first.

Here changes to `b[2]` affect the value calculated for `b[3]` and on down the line.

`add.at` and other such `ufunc` do unbuffered calculations.  This allows you to add some value repeatedly to one element.  I played a bit with it in that case, but no luck so far.

`cumsum` and `cumprod` are also handy for problems were values depend earlier ones.

Is it possible to generalize the calculation, so as to as define `b[i]` in terms of all the `a[:i]`.  We know `b[2]` as a function of `a[:2]`, but what of `b[3]`?

Even if we go this working for floats, it might be off when doing integer divisions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have the sane solution. Any other vectorization would rely on floating point calculations and it would be really difficult to keep track of the error accumulation. For example say you want to have a matrix vector multiplication: for the first seven terms the matrix would look like

```
array([[ 1.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ],
       [ 0.     ,  1.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ],
       [ 0.5    ,  0.5    ,  1.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ],
       [ 0.25   ,  0.75   ,  0.5    ,  1.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ],
       [ 0.375  ,  0.625  ,  0.75   ,  0.5    ,  1.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ],
       [ 0.3125 ,  0.6875 ,  0.625  ,  0.75   ,  0.5    ,  1.     ,  0.     ],
       [ 0.34375,  0.65625,  0.6875 ,  0.625  ,  0.75   ,  0.5    ,  1.     ]])
```

The relationship can be described as the iterative formula

```
                       [ a[i-2] ]
b[i] = [0.5 , 0.5 , 1] [ a[i-1] ]
                       [ a[i]   ]
```

That defines a series of elementary matrices of the form of an identity matrix with

```
[0 ... 0.5 0.5 1 0 ... 0]
```

on the ith row. And successive multiplication gives the matrix above for the first seven terms. There is indeed a subdiagonal structure but the terms are getting too small very quickly. As you have shown 2 to the power 500k is not fun.

In order to keep track of floating point noise, an iterative solution is required which is what you have anyways.